# Why do i get EOFError: Ran out of input, when running model = pickle.load(open('filename.pkl', 'rb')) in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to read and load a pickle file. Even though the pickle object I am trying to pass as argument is not empty I am getting this issue.

Code:

```
model = pickle.load(open('ridge-model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Error:

EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: why not save the pickle object vlue in another object and pass that another oject to model ?

Comment: I tried that too. I am able to run a= open("filename.pkl", "rb"). But pickle.load(a) gives error.

Comment: Yes. The file was empty somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when the file you are trying to load with `pickle` is empty.

So make sure that there's things written into `'ridge-model.pkl'`.